# ChartJs Doughnut parsing datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I‘m trying to create a doughnut chart with custom objects as data. I don’t know if it is a bug or am I stupid. 
If the type of the chart is „bar“ everything is working as expected but if I change it to doughnut the chart area is empty.

Here is the code for the bar chart:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [{vX:12, n:'vx'}, {vX:13, n:'vx2'}],
            parsing:{
                yAxisKey:'vX',
              xAxisKey: 'n'
            },
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        
    }
});
```

and that‘s my doughnut:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [{vX:12, n:'vx'}, {vX:13, n:'vx2'}],
            parsing:{
                yAxisKey:'vX',
              
            },
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        
    }
});
```

Is parsing not supported for doughnut charts? I can‘t find information about this in the docs.

thanks, Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment chart.js does not support object notation with parsing for pie/doughnut charts.

There has been a [pr](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/9622) for this a few days ago which is merged into the master so as soon as a new version of chart.js releases, anything beyond version 3.5.1 will have this change in it and then you can use your object.

Otherwise you can take the route @uminder suggested and map the data yourself

Comment: Hi LeeLenalee, thank you and what a great news.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding [data structures](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure), the Chart.js documentation says:

> For a pie (and doughnut) chart, datasets need to contain an array of data points. The data points should be a number (...)

Therefore, parsing doesn't make sense and is probably not supported. The problem can be solved by mapping your data to `labels` and `data` as follows.

```js
var data = [{vX:12, n:'vx'}, {vX:13, n:'vx2'}];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: data.map(v => v.n),
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: data.map(v => v.vX),     
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi uminder, how could I skip that? OMG! 
Thank you so much … in the meantime I follow your suggestion until 3.6.0 is available.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Christian, It's available since 3.6.0 (2021-10-24, see https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9440) with sth. like this:

```js
    options: {
      parsing: {
        key: "the-label-key',
      }
    }
```

ref official doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html